# how to avoid change of class on assigning derived class object to base class object in c# 4?

Tags: c#-4.0

Hello from C# and OOP newbie.

How can I avoid change of class on assigning derived class object to base class object in c#?
After i run code bellow i get this response

**obj1 is TestingField.Two

obj2 is TestingField.Two**

I expected that i will lose access to derived methods and properties (which I did) after assigning reference but I did not expect change of class in midcode :S

```
using System;

namespace TestingField
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            One obj1 = new One();
            Two obj2 = new Two();
            obj1 = obj2;
            Console.WriteLine("obj1 is {0}", obj1.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("obj2 is {0}", obj2.GetType());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class One
    {
    }

    class Two : One
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Did Something.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that runtime and declared type of instantiated object obj1 are not the same which can represent problem with L2E `AddObject` method which throws `System.InvalidOperationException` - Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'TestingField.obj2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are right, you will lose access to members **declared** in the derived type, the object won't suddenly change it's type or **implementation**. You can access only members declared on the base type, but the implementation of the derived type is used in the case of overriden members, which is the case with `GetType`, which is a compiler generated method which automatically overrides the base class's implementation.

Extending your example:

```
class One
{
   public virtual void SayHello()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello from Base");
   }
}

class Two : One
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Did Something.");
    }
    public override void SayHello()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello from Derived");
    }

}
```

Given:

```
One obj = new Two();
obj.SayHello(); // will return "Hello from Derived"
```

Comment: I think I understands now. In my example both `obj1.GetType()` and `obj2.GetType()` are actually members of class Two. I guess my question should be "How can I prevent usage of derived members on assigning derived class object reference to base class object reference?"

Answer (score 1):

`GetType` is a virtual method gives you the *dynamic type* of the object.

I think you want the *static type* of the variable. You can't get this by calling a method on the object referenced by the variable. Instead just write `typeof(TypeName)`, which is `typeof(One)` or `typeof(Two)` in your case.

Alternatively in your subclass you can use a new method which hides the original one instead of overriding it:

```
class One
{
    public string MyGetType() { return "One";  }
}

class Two : One
{
    public new string MyGetType() { return "Two"; }
}

class Program
{
    private void Run()
    {
        One obj1 = new One();
        Two obj2 = new Two();
        obj1 = obj2;

        Console.WriteLine("obj1.GetType(): " + obj1.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("obj2.GetType(): " + obj2.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("obj1.MyGetType(): " + obj1.MyGetType());
        Console.WriteLine("obj2.MyGetType(): " + obj2.MyGetType());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
obj1.GetType(): Two
obj2.GetType(): Two
obj1.MyGetType(): One
obj2.MyGetType(): Two
```

Comment: While you are correct of course, this isn't the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't "changed class". The type of the variable `obj1` is still `One`. You have assigned an instance of `Two` to this variable, which is allowed since `Two` inherits from `One`. The `GetType` method gives you the actual type of the object currently referenced by this variable, not the type of the declared variable itself.

Comment: This isn't true, typeof only works on declerations, not variables.